Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem
I'm looking at the LRN theorem in Rudin's Real and complex analysis.

6.10 The Theorem of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym Let $\mu$ be a positive $\sigma$-finite
measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\frak{M}$ in a set $X$, and let $\lambda$ be a complex measure on $\frak{M}$.
(a) There is then a unique pair of complex measures $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_s$ on $\frak{M}$ such that $$\lambda = \lambda_a + \lambda_s,\quad \lambda_a \ll \mu,\quad \lambda_s \perp \mu.$$
If $\lambda$ is positive and finite, then so are $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_s$.
(b) There is a unique $h \in L^1 (\mu)$ such that
$$\lambda_a (E) = \int_E h\ d\mu$$
for every set $E \in \frak{M}$.

I can't figure out why $h$ would be Lebesgue integrable. Wouldn't that imply that $\lambda_a$ was a priori a finite measure (since $\lambda_a (X) = \int_X h\ d\mu < \infty$)? I might be missing something obvious, but this does not make any sense to me. I think item (b) should say that $h$ is a measurable function that is unique up to a zero measure set or something like that.

Is it because in the proof, such $h$ exists and is defined to be $g/(1-g)$ where $g$ exists and unique by Riesz Representation Thm, thus $h$ is unique?

$\lambda_a$ is a complex measure thus $|\lambda_a|(X)<\infty$. By defintion of complex measures $\lambda_a(X)\in\mathbb C$, so that by defintion complex measures are always bounded; we do not allow $\infty$ in the range as for positive measures

Note that the theorem doesn't say there's a unique function $h$; it says there's a unique element of $L^1$. Since elements of $L^1$ are equivalence classes, with respect to a.e. equality, your problem about uniqueness up to a measure zero set evaporates.

@GhostAmarth Right, I totally forgot about that. It's immediately in the next paragraph after the proof as well. Thanks for your comment.

@AndreasBlass This is irrelevant to the question.

@the_dude In that case, I didn't understand the last sentnce of the question, "I think item (b) should say that ℎ is a measurable function that is unique up to a zero measure set or something like that." My comment points out that item (b) says exactly what you think it should. That's what I meant by saying that this "problem ... eaporates."

@AndreasBlass No, (b) doesn't say that. It says that $\int_X |h| \ d\mu < \infty$ on top of $h$ being measurable. To repeat everything already said in the post: I didn't understand how that is possible without a priori assuming $\lambda_a$ is a finite measure. Turns out that is exactly what we assumed since complex measures are finite by definition.
